# Flutter Navigator default route route in Fluro package

Tags: flutter, router, flutter-navigation

I am using Flutter with [Fluro](https://pub.dev/packages/fluro) package and I want to set a default route for the app.

The need is to have a place to decide which path the user needs to navigate to, and from there to navigate the app by whatever settings decided upon.

Currently, I defined the routes in the app and do have a "404" (not found) route as described in the docs of the package, but I prefer to have another way which is more correct to solve it.

For example, the app has the routes:

```
"homepage"
"splash_screen"
"search"
"not_found"
"init"
```

I want the route `init` to be the default one.

Thank you,
Nisim

Answer (score 2):

After digging some more I found the Fluro package has internal class `RouteTree` which handles all routes. when adding a new route it will check if it defaults by comparing it to `Navigator.defaultRouteName` (value `"/"`).

**Note:** it allow you to add only one default route and will throw an exception if you do it more then one.

Adding the default route with handler solved the issue and now the default route is the one deciding about the next route and displays something in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me!